# React Bootstrap footer display col vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple footer and I want it to be split in three parts. However the footer is stacked vertically instead of horizontally as you can see on this picture : [image]

**What I've tried**

Following the [React Bootstrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/layout/grid/#rb-docs-content) I coded the following :

```css
/* --------- */
/* Footer */
/* --------- */

.footer-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  background-color: rgb(10, 4, 22);
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  h3 {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
}

.footer-copywright {
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-body {
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-icons {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .footer-copywright {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footer-body {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<Container className="footer-container">
  <Row>
    <Col md={4} className="footer-copywright">
    <h3>Designed and Developed by TODO</h3>
    </Col>
    <Col md={4} className="footer-copywright">
    <h3>Copyright © TODO</h3>
    </Col>
    <Col md={4} className="footer-body">
    <ul className="footer-icons">
      <li className="social-icons">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/xyz" style={{ color: "black" }} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          xyz
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

I can't figure out why it's stacking vertically and not horizontally

Comment: `Col` expects `xs`/`sm`/`md`/`lg` prop value in either `boolean` or `number`. You are passing it as string. Here is the documentation for same https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/layout/grid/#col-props So change `md="4"` to `md={4}`.

Comment: I appreciate your help but the issue remains the same